# Query by discriminator in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I did some searching on this and didn't turn up anything. Is it possible to create a Hibernate query to return a set of objects based on a discriminator?

I have an AbstractUser class which is extended by the concrete classes UserTypeA and UserTypeB. I'm using the table-per-hierarchy model to map my classes in NHibernate, so UserTypeA and UserTypeB are both stored in the same table with different discriminator values. Here is my discriminator mapping property:

```
<discriminator column="Type" type="string"/>
```

I have a column in my table that contains the name of the user type. I'm wondering if it's possible to run a NHibernate query using this.

I tried this:

```
public IList<DomainBase> FindByType(string typeName, Type type)
{
    string query = "from " + type.Name + " k where k.Type = " + typeName;
    return Session.CreateQuery(query).List<DomainBase>();
}
```

But since Type is not actually a property of the class, just a column in the table, this obviously doesn't work. It would seem redundant to have both a property for this purpose and a discriminator, unless there's a way to use a property as a discriminator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, this is well documented at http://www.nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-where:

> Likewise, the special property `class`
>   accesses the discriminator value of an
>   instance in the case of polymorphic
>   persistence. A .Net class name
>   embedded in the where clause will be
>   translated to its discriminator value.
>
> ```
>  from Eg.Cat cat where cat.class = Eg.DomesticCat
> ```

You can also pass a `System.Type` instance as a parameter.

Comment: Is this possible with criteria API?

Answer (score 2):

If you really only want to query on the type, then I think using the ICriteria API is a more convenient option:

```
public IList<T> FindByType<T>()
{
    return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
}
```

Now you can use it like `IList<UserTypeB> list = FindByType<UserTypeB>()`.