# NHibernate could not resolve propery "class"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance

I am having problem and the time spend beeing stuck tells me, to ask stackOverflow community. So:
I have basic versioning system for files represented as abstract class FileSystemEntry (FSE) which has 2 childs - File and Folder. There is also FileSystemEntryVersion (FSEV). FSE has many FSEV.

```
public abstract class FileSystemEntry
{
    public FileSystemEntry(){}

    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual IList<FileSystemEntryVersion> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the FSEV:

```
public class FileSystemEntryVersion {
    public FileSystemEntryVersion(){}

    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    //pointer to physical file/folder
    public virtual FileSystemEntry FileSystemEntry { get; set; }

    //pointer to parent file/folder
    public virtual FileSystemEntry ParentFolder { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the hbm.xml file for FSE (the most important part)

```
<class name="FileSystemEntry" table="[FileSystemEntry]" abstract="true">
<id name="Id" type="Int64">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>

<discriminator column="Type"
               not-null="true"
               type="String"/>
<subclass name="File"
          discriminator-value="File"/>

<subclass name="Folder"
          discriminator-value="Folder"/>
</class>
```

Every FSEV (has parent folder). I want to make a query, which gets only folders contained in parent folder. My current query is:

```
 IList<FileSystemEntryVersion> versions =
                session.CreateCriteria<FileSystemEntryVersion>()
                       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ParentFolder.Id", parentFolderId))
                       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("FileSystemEntry.class", typeof(Folder)))))
                       .List<FileSystemEntryVersion>();

            return versions;
```

But the property "class" in FileSystemEntry.class is said it couldn't be resolved. Why?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283070/nhibernate-query-by-discriminator-on-association

Comment: @Najera Yes, I did. But got same exception, until I tried to make alias this way: CreateAliast("FileSystemEntry", "FileSystemEntry")... but I wasn´t sure at all why does it work suddenly :) Radim Kohler set it clear, but I swear, I tried it and it didnt work yesterday:D Now it does..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
var versions = session
     .CreateCriteria<FileSystemEntryVersion>()
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ParentFolder.Id", parentFolderId))

     // we do need a reference here, JOIN in fact, 
     // to include the Many-to-One table          
     .CreateAlias("FileSystemEntry ", "Entry")

     // now the SELECT will contain even the FileSystemEntry table
     // and can start evaluate
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Entry.class", typeof(Folder)))))
     .List<FileSystemEntryVersion>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's it :) But as I said to Najera, I thought I tried it and it didn't work. Now it does. Greetings from Prague to Prague :)

Comment: Cool if that helped ;) Good luck with NHibernate. It is amazing tool ;)